# OkHttp Interceptor chain broken when getting token

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an OkHttp Interceptor which should ask for a token when the request is getting a 401 HTTP error. Now, the request to login service is done but then the chain is broken and the original request is not retried. 
Here is the intercept method of my interceptor:

```java
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        logger.d("AuthenticationServiceHolder $authenticationServiceHolder")

        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        logger.d("Intercepting call to ${originalRequest.method()} ${originalRequest.url()}")

        val response: Response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)
        val successful = response.isSuccessful
        val code = response.code()
        logger.d("Response successful: $successful - code: $code")

        if (!successful && code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            logger.d("Token is $token")

            val deviceUuid = deviceIdentificationManager.deviceUuid().blockingGet()
            logger.d("Device uuid $deviceUuid")
            if (deviceUuid != null) {
                val authenticationService = authenticationServiceHolder.get()
                if (authenticationService != null) {
                    token = reLogin(authenticationService, deviceUuid)
                    if (token != null) {
                        val headersBuilder = originalRequest.headers().newBuilder()
                        headersBuilder.removeAll(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
                        headersBuilder.add(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, token!!)

                        val requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                        val request = requestBuilder.headers(headersBuilder.build()).build()
                        return chain.proceed(request)
                    } else {
                        logger.e("Token was not retrieved")
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.e("Authentication service is null!")
                }
            }
        }
        return response
}
```

The reLogin() method is:

```java
private fun reLogin(authenticationService: AuthenticationService, deviceUuid: UUID): String? {
        logger.d("reLogin() - authenticationService $authenticationService")
        val blockingGet = authenticationService?.login(LoginRequest(deviceUuid, clock.currentTime()))?.blockingGet()
        logger.d("reLogin() - response $blockingGet")
        val response = blockingGet ?: return null
        logger.d("reLogin() - token ${response.token}")
        return response.token
}
```

NEW:
As [Mitesh Machhoya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3664852/mitesh-machhoya) says, I've tried with 2 different instances of retrofit, one has the okhttp client with the interceptor and the another doesn't have it.
And now the login call is not intercepted but the execution of the Interceptor is broken, I mean the log trace of this class is:

```
 - AuthenticationServiceHolder XXXmypackageXXX.AuthenticationServiceHolder... 
 - Intercepting call to GET XXXmyInterceptedCallXXX 
 - Response successful: false - code: 401 
 - Token is null 
 - Device uuid XXX 
 - reLogin() - authenticationService retrofit2.Retrofit$1@a5c0a25
```

And nothing more. I mean `reLogin() - response.....` is not printed. I'm sure that the login call is working because I see the login response in okhttp log.

Comment: okhttp Authenticator is easier to work with for 401 handling and retries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code pasted is working well, the Login request is working but the response of login was changed on server side and the deserialisation made it crash and it broke the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Make reLogin request with other httpClient without attaching interceptor, then it will work well as you expected.

if you make reLogin request with same httpClient then it will gone through the interceptor and it override request everytime so try to make request using another httpClient

Comment: I've just tried it and now the login call is not intercepted but the execution of the Interceptor is broken, I mean the log trace of this class is:

- AuthenticationServiceHolder XXXmypackageXXX.AuthenticationServiceHolder...


- Intercepting call to GET https://XXXmyInterceptedCallXXX


- Response successful: false - code: 401


- Token is null


- Device uuid XXX


- reLogin() - authenticationService retrofit2.Retrofit$1@a5c0a25



And nothing more. It should be `reLogin() - response....`. I'm sure that the login call is working because I see the response with okhttp log

Comment: don't make call with blocking, make async call and see what is happening

Comment: AFAIK, calls inside the interceptors have to be synchronous... if not, how can I add the token to the header?